# How to add test device in Admob android

Tags: android

I am trying to add AdMob into my project. I have added everything and the actual ad appears. I need to add the test ad's, but no joy.

```
AdView mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

How to I add the testDevice to this. I get the following in logcat. I am new. Pls help.

```
Use AdRequest.Builder.addTestDevice("C56DDF777176380265C737EAE019B2CB")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

```
 AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()


     .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
     .addTestDevice("asdfasdfasd234234")
            .build();


    adView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

Comment: Are both these test device lines required to add a real phone as a test device? What should be used as device id? IMEI or something else?